# QT Windows to Android necessity project changes

Tags: android, c++, qt, openssl, crypto++

I have a project which uses Crypto++, OpenSSL and QT 5.5.1 framework. Its for x86 Qindows with MSVC 12.0 compiler.

Now I want to run this project on android virtual device Nexus S. I have installed JDK, SDK, NDK, runed Nexus S for armebi architecture, GCC 4.9 compiler and QT 5.5.1 for Android armv5.

The Android Virtual Device (AVD) starts and run some examples successfully, but my program is not running in the same way. Here is .pro file:

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2015-11-20T12:41:07
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = EPsimple
TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp\
    mainwindow.cpp \
    statusdialog.cpp \
    model.cpp \
    logindialog.cpp \
    threadedcontroller.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
    statusdialog.h \
    model.h \
    logindialog.h \
    threadedcontroller.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui \
    statusdialog.ui \
    logindialog.ui

INCLUDEPATH += C:\OpenSSL-Win32\include
INCLUDEPATH += C:\Users\niki\Downloads\cryptopp563rc5-1

debug{
LIBS += -LC:\Users\niki\Downloads\cryptopp563rc5-1\Win32\Output\Release \
-lcryptlib
LIBS += -LC:\OpenSSL-Win32\lib\VC \
-llibeay32MDd
}

release{
LIBS += -LC:\Users\niki\Downloads\cryptopp563rc5-1\Win32\Output\Debug \
-lcryptlib
LIBS += -LC:\OpenSSL-Win32\lib\VC \
-llibeay32MD
}

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE += /MD
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_DEBUG += /MDd
#QMAKE_LFLAGS += /STACK:32000000
#QMAKE_LFLAGS += /HEAP:32000000
```

Following error occurs:

> :-1: error: error: /MD: No such file or directory

Is it necessary to compile cryptopp and openssl libraries for GCC 4.9 compiler and what will happen with /MD and /MT options (are they still available for android)? The whole code can be seen from [here](http://cryptofm.com/) (second version).

Comment: You should start a clean rebuild. Next you would need the libraries for android (or compile them yourself), and link against these.

Comment: Can you help me [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33953855/qt-5-5-1-so-library-with-android). I have downloaded openssl for android but it gives me `collect2.exe:-1: error: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it necessary to compile cryptopp and openssl libraries for GCC 4.9 compiler

Yes. You can set-up the QT project to compile Crypto++ under the environment. Or, see [Android (Command Line)](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Android_%28Command_Line%29) on the Crypto++ wiki.

---

> ```
> QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE += /MD
> QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_DEBUG += /MDd
> ```
>
> ... 
>   :-1: error: error: /MD: No such file or directory

This is a Windows compiler linker switch. `/MD` specifies linking with the [Multithreaded DLL version of the runtime library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzt1wy3.aspx). You should not be using it for an Android project.

It sounds like you need to add a new configuration to your QT project. Your best bet is to probably create a new QT project and keep them separate.

I believe Wei Dai's GitHub has a pull request for an `Android.mk`. We want to incorporate it into the library eventually. See [Add Android.mk to build using android NDK](http://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/pull/3). (Wei is the author of Crypto++).

Comment: Thank you noloader. I took precompiled version of cryptopp from you [here](https://github.com/noloader) and openssl from another place, becouse your is missing.

Comment: @nicksona - also see [Add Android.mk to build using android NDK](http://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/pull/3) pull request. We want to add it eventually.

Comment: I am not shure how good cryptopp is working for android - can see my thread [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34048195/cryptopp-fatal-signal-11). I think it is some bug in the library but could not find it.