# QT 5.5.1 .so library with android

Tags: android, c++, qt, openssl, shared-libraries

I have downloaded openssl compiled library for armeabi and x86 android platforms from [here](https://github.com/emileb/OpenSSL-for-Android-Prebuilt) and tried to load it in the .pro file:

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:\Temp\openssl\OpenSSL-for-Android-Prebuilt\openssl-1.0.2\include\
LIBS += -LC:\Temp\openssl\OpenSSL-for-Android-Prebuilt\openssl-1.0.2\armeabi-v7a\lib \
-llibssl
-llibcrypto
```

I have also tried with `-llibssl.so -llibcrypto.so` and `-llibssl.a -llibcrypto.a` but this error occures:

> collect2.exe:-1: error: error: ld returned 1 exit status

The code is simple usage of SHA1 and it is running on MSVC 12.0 with .lib libraries successfully:

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "QMessageBox"
#include <openssl/sha.h>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    const unsigned char ibuf[] = "compute sha1";
    const char ibuf1[] = "compute sha1";
    unsigned char obuf[20];

    SHA1(ibuf, strlen(ibuf1), obuf);

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        printf("%02x ", obuf[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QMessageBox::about(this,tr("Test"),tr("Hellow man!!!"));
}
```

Of course I have read forums so here is the full log:

```
C:\Users\niki\Downloads\android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ --sysroot=C:\Users\niki\Downloads\android-ndk-r10e/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/ -Wl,-soname,libtestAndroid.so -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -shared -o libtestAndroid.so main.obj mainwindow.obj moc_mainwindow.obj   -LC:\Users\niki\Downloads\android-ndk-r10e/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/armeabi -LC:\Users\niki\Downloads\android-ndk-r10e/platforms/android-9/arch-arm//usr/lib -LC:/Qt/5.5/android_armv5/lib -lQt5Widgets -Lc:\utils\android\ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.8/libs/armeabi -Lc:\utils\android\ndk/platforms/android-9/arch-arm//usr/lib -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core -lGLESv2 -lgnustl_shared -llog -lz -lm -ldl -lc -lgcc
mainwindow.obj:mainwindow.cpp:function MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget*): error: undefined reference to 'SHA1'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
makefile:83: recipe for target 'libtestAndroid.so' failed
mingw32-make: *** [libtestAndroid.so] Error 1
10:47:05: The process "C:\Qt\Tools\mingw492_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project testAndroid (kit: Android for armeabi (GCC 4.9, Qt 5.5.1))
When executing step "Make"
```

It seems that SHA1 is the problem. In sha.h it is defined

```
#ifdef  __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
#ifdef  __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

so this is not the issue. There is some Android.mk file. What to do? Should I load it somehow in .pro file? I just wanted to try usage of openssl in android before compile it to be shure it is possible to work(because compilling will take time and must be done on linux).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question was noobie. Seems when you want to link shared libraries begining with "lib" you should miss it so in my case this worked:

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:\Temp\openssl\OpenSSL-for-Android-Prebuilt\openssl-1.0.2\include\
LIBS += -LC:\Temp\openssl\OpenSSL-for-Android-Prebuilt\openssl-1.0.2\armeabi-v7a\lib -lssl
LIBS += -LC:\Temp\openssl\OpenSSL-for-Android-Prebuilt\openssl-1.0.2\armeabi-v7a\lib -lcrypto
```

Notice I have separated `libcrypto.so and libssl.so` from  `libcrypto.a and libssl.a` in two directories - lib and lib1. For me only static libs(.a) worked, shared libs give me error.