# Cryptopp fatal signal 11

Tags: c++, qt, android-ndk, openssl, crypto++

Here is log1 aplication output:

```
   :    ... 25 more
W/System.err( 1500): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable
W/System.err( 1500):    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
W/System.err( 1500):    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:217)
W/System.err( 1500):    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:172)
W/System.err( 1500):    at org.qtproject.qt5.android.ExtractStyle.getClass(ExtractStyle.java:388)
W/System.err( 1500):    at org.qtproject.qt5.android.ExtractStyle.<init>(ExtractStyle.java:94)
W/System.err( 1500):    at org.qtproject.qt5.android.QtActivityDelegate.loadApplication(QtActivityDelegate.java:430)
W/System.err( 1500):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/System.err( 1500):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
W/System.err( 1500):    at org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity.loadApplication(QtActivity.java:245)
W/System.err( 1500):    at org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity.startApp(QtActivity.java:655)
W/System.err( 1500):    at org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity.onCreate(QtActivity.java:895)
W/System.err( 1500):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5275)
W/System.err( 1500):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1082)
W/System.err( 1500):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2049)
W/System.err( 1500):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
W/System.err( 1500):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:138)
W/System.err( 1500):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205)
W/System.err( 1500):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
W/System.err( 1500):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
W/System.err( 1500):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4950)
W/System.err( 1500):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/System.err( 1500):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
W/System.err( 1500):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:798)
W/System.err( 1500):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:565)
W/System.err( 1500):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
W/System.err( 1500): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawable
W/System.err( 1500):    ... 25 more
W/System.err( 1500): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable
W/System.err( 1500):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
W/System.err( 1500):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
W/System.err( 1500):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
W/System.err( 1500):    ... 25 more
W/System.err( 1500): java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: View_paddingStart
W/System.err( 1500):    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:631)
W/System.err( 1500):    at org.qtproject.qt5.android.ExtractStyle.getField(ExtractStyle.java:427)
W/System.err( 1500):    at org.qtproject.qt5.android.ExtractStyle.<init>(ExtractStyle.java:173)
W/System.err( 1500):    at org.qtproject.qt5.android.QtActivityDelegate.loadApplication(QtActivityDelegate.java:430)
W/System.err( 1500):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/System.err( 1500):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
W/System.err( 1500):    at org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity.loadApplication(QtActivity.java:245)
W/System.err( 1500):    at org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity.startApp(QtActivity.java:655)
W/System.err( 1500):    at org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity.onCreate(QtActivity.java:895)
W/System.err( 1500):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5275)
W/System.err( 1500):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1082)
W/System.err( 1500):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2049)
W/System.err( 1500):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
W/System.err( 1500):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:138)
W/System.err( 1500):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205)
W/System.err( 1500):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
W/System.err( 1500):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
W/System.err( 1500):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4950)
W/System.err( 1500):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/System.err( 1500):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
W/System.err( 1500):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:798)
W/System.err( 1500):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:565)
W/System.err( 1500):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
W/System.err( 1500): java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: View_paddingEnd
W/System.err( 1500):    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:631)
W/System.err( 1500):    at org.qtproject.qt5.android.ExtractStyle.getField(ExtractStyle.java:427)
W/System.err( 1500):    at org.qtproject.qt5.android.ExtractStyle.<init>(ExtractStyle.java:174)
W/System.err( 1500):    at org.qtproject.qt5.android.QtActivityDelegate.loadApplication(QtActivityDelegate.java:430)
W/System.err( 1500):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/System.err( 1500):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
W/System.err( 1500):    at org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity.loadApplication(QtActivity.java:245)
W/System.err( 1500):    at org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity.startApp(QtActivity.java:655)
W/System.err( 1500):    at org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity.onCreate(QtActivity.java:895)
W/System.err( 1500):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5275)
W/System.err( 1500):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1082)
W/System.err( 1500):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2049)
W/System.err( 1500):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
W/System.err( 1500):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:138)
W/System.err( 1500):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205)
W/System.err( 1500):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
W/System.err( 1500):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
W/System.err( 1500):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4950)
W/System.err( 1500):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/System.err( 1500):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
W/System.err( 1500):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:798)
W/System.err( 1500):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:565)
W/System.err( 1500):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
D/dalvikvm( 1500): GC_CONCURRENT freed 494K, 14% free 5744K/6663K, paused 81ms+191ms, total 320ms
D/dalvikvm( 1500): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 18ms
W/ResourceType( 1500): Skipping entry 0x10804c7 in package table 0 because it is not complex!
D/dalvikvm( 1500): GC_CONCURRENT freed 462K, 14% free 5843K/6727K, paused 34ms+3ms, total 75ms
D/dalvikvm( 1500): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 18ms
D/dalvikvm( 1500): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 541K, 15% free 5829K/6791K, paused 18ms, total 18ms
D/dalvikvm( 1500): GC_CONCURRENT freed 409K, 13% free 5932K/6791K, paused 55ms+3ms, total 95ms
D/dalvikvm( 1500): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 40ms
D/dalvikvm( 1500): GC_CONCURRENT freed 501K, 14% free 5990K/6919K, paused 67ms+2ms, total 100ms
D/dalvikvm( 1500): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 36ms
D/dalvikvm( 1500): GC_CONCURRENT freed 544K, 15% free 5999K/6983K, paused 2ms+3ms, total 63ms
D/dalvikvm( 1500): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 44ms
D/dalvikvm( 1500): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 477K, 14% free 6032K/6983K, paused 17ms, total 18ms
D/dalvikvm( 1500): GC_CONCURRENT freed 479K, 14% free 6065K/6983K, paused 63ms+2ms, total 106ms
D/dalvikvm( 1500): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 43ms
D/dalvikvm( 1500): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 489K, 14% free 6072K/7047K, paused 19ms, total 20ms
D/dalvikvm( 1500): GC_CONCURRENT freed 438K, 13% free 6137K/7047K, paused 31ms+3ms, total 72ms
D/dalvikvm( 1500): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 43ms
D/dalvikvm( 1500): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 299K, 14% free 6143K/7111K, paused 19ms, total 19ms
D/dalvikvm( 1500): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 30K, 14% free 6156K/7111K, paused 19ms, total 19ms
D/dalvikvm( 1500): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 38K, 14% free 6149K/7111K, paused 19ms, total 19ms
D/dalvikvm( 1500): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 499K, 14% free 6158K/7111K, paused 20ms, total 21ms
D/dalvikvm( 1500): GC_CONCURRENT freed 531K, 14% free 6138K/7111K, paused 17ms+3ms, total 80ms
D/dalvikvm( 1500): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 63ms
I/Adreno200-EGL( 1500): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:299>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_REL_2.0.3_RB3.04.01.01.42.006_msm7627a_JB_REL_2.0.3_Merge_release_AU (Merge)
I/Adreno200-EGL( 1500): Build Date: 04/01/13 Mon
I/Adreno200-EGL( 1500): Local Branch:
I/Adreno200-EGL( 1500): Remote Branch: m/jb_rel_2.0.3
I/Adreno200-EGL( 1500): Local Patches: NONE
I/Adreno200-EGL( 1500): Reconstruct Branch: NOTHING
I/Choreographer( 1500): Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
D/libtestAndroid4.so( 1500): (null):0 ((null)): -----------------------------P-8------------------------------------
D/libtestAndroid4.so( 1500): (null):0 ((null)): -----------------------------P-9------------------------------------
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 1500): getCursorCapsMode on inactive InputConnection
D/libtestAndroid4.so( 1500): (null):0 ((null)): -----------------------------P-2------------------------------------
F/libc    ( 1500): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x007a7a76 (code=1), thread 1567 (le.testAndroid4)
I/DEBUG   (  147): pid: 1500, tid: 1567, name: le.testAndroid4  >>> org.qtproject.example.testAndroid4 <<<


"org.qtproject.example.testAndroid4" died.
```

log1 compile output:

```
Android package built successfully in 29.282 ms.
  -- It can now be run from the selected device/emulator.
  -- File: C:/Users/niki/Documents/build-testAndroid4-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_5_1-Release/android-build//bin/QtApp-debug.apk
3064 KB/s (15889430 bytes in 5.064s)
11:15:26: The process "C:/Qt/5.5/android_armv7/bin/androiddeployqt.exe" exited normally.
11:15:26: Pulling files necessary for debugging.
11:15:26: Package deploy: Running command "C:/Users/niki/AppData/Local/Android/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb.exe -s LGOTMS328ac0aa pull /system/bin/sh: readlink: not found C:/Users/niki/Documents/build-testAndroid4-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_5_1-Release/app_process".
11:15:26: Packaging error: Command "C:/Users/niki/AppData/Local/Android/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb.exe -s LGOTMS328ac0aa pull /system/bin/sh: readlink: not found C:/Users/niki/Documents/build-testAndroid4-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_5_1-Release/app_process" failed.Exit code: 1
11:15:26: Package deploy: Running command "C:/Users/niki/AppData/Local/Android/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb.exe -s LGOTMS328ac0aa pull /system/lib/libc.so C:/Users/niki/Documents/build-testAndroid4-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_5_1-Release/libc.so".
11:15:26: Elapsed time: 00:53.
```

log2 application output:

```
 ...
    I/Adreno200-EGL( 3188): Build Date: 04/01/13 Mon
    I/Adreno200-EGL( 3188): Local Branch:
    I/Adreno200-EGL( 3188): Remote Branch: m/jb_rel_2.0.3
    I/Adreno200-EGL( 3188): Local Patches: NONE
    I/Adreno200-EGL( 3188): Reconstruct Branch: NOTHING
    D/libtestAndroid4.so( 3188): (null):0 ((null)): -----------------------------P-8------------------------------------
    D/libtestAndroid4.so( 3188): (null):0 ((null)): -----------------------------P-9------------------------------------
    D/libtestAndroid4.so( 3188): (null):0 ((null)): -----------------------------P-2------------------------------------
    D/libtestAndroid4.so( 3188): (null):0 ((null)): -----------------------------P-3------------------------------------
    D/libtestAndroid4.so( 3188): (null):0 ((null)): -----------------------------P-4------------------------------------
    D/libtestAndroid4.so( 3188): (null):0 ((null)): -----------------------------P-5------------------------------------
    D/libtestAndroid4.so( 3188): (null):0 ((null)): -----------------------------P-10------------------------------------
    D/libtestAndroid4.so( 3188): (null):0 ((null)): -----------------------------P-1------------------------------------
    D/libtestAndroid4.so( 3188): (null):0 ((null)): -----------------------------P-11------------------------------------
    D/libtestAndroid4.so( 3188): (null):0 ((null)): -----------------------------P-12------------------------------------
    D/libtestAndroid4.so( 3188): (null):0 ((null)): -----------------------------P-2------------------------------------
    D/libtestAndroid4.so( 3188): (null):0 ((null)): -----------------------------P-3------------------------------------
    D/libtestAndroid4.so( 3188): (null):0 ((null)): -----------------------------P-4------------------------------------
    D/libtestAndroid4.so( 3188): (null):0 ((null)): -----------------------------P-5------------------------------------
    D/libtestAndroid4.so( 3188): (null):0 ((null)): -----------------------------P-13------------------------------------
    D/libtestAndroid4.so( 3188): (null):0 ((null)): -----------------------------P-14------------------------------------
    F/libc    ( 3188): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadcab1 (code=1), thread 3269 (le.testAndroid4)
    I/DEBUG   (  147): pid: 3188, tid: 3269, name: le.testAndroid4  >>> org.qtproject.example.testAndroid4 <<<
    I/ActivityManager(  457): Process org.qtproject.example.testAndroid4 (pid 3188) has died.


    "org.qtproject.example.testAndroid4" died.
```

Now the source code:

**logindialog.h**

```
#ifndef LOGINDIALOG_H
#define LOGINDIALOG_H

#include <QDialog>
#include <QDebug>
namespace Ui {
class loginDialog;
}

class loginDialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit loginDialog(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~loginDialog();
    bool isDecrypted();
    std::string getPassword();

private slots:
    void on_passwordButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::loginDialog *ui;
    bool decrypted;
    std::string password;
};

#endif // LOGINDIALOG_H
```

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

#include <fstream> 
//#include <sha.h>
//#include <pwdbased.h>
//#include <osrng.h>
//#include <sstream>
//#include <iomanip>
//#include <cryptlib.h>
//using CryptoPP::Exception;

//#include <hex.h>
//using CryptoPP::HexEncoder;
//using CryptoPP::HexDecoder;

//#include <filters.h>
//using CryptoPP::StringSink;
#include "logindialog.h"
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QDebug>
namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:    
    void on_pushButton_2_clicked();
    void on_pushButton_clicked();
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    bool getEnterPassword(std::string &);
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**logindialog.cpp**

```
#include "logindialog.h"
#include "ui_logindialog.h"

loginDialog::loginDialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::loginDialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

loginDialog::~loginDialog()
{
    delete ui;
}

void loginDialog::on_passwordButton_clicked()
{
     qDebug() << "-----------------------------P-2------------------------------------";
    this->password = ui->lineEdit->text().toStdString();
      qDebug() << "-----------------------------P-3------------------------------------";
    this->decrypted = true; //TODO decrypt the file and if there is exception set as false
       qDebug() << "-----------------------------P-4------------------------------------";
    this->accept();
        qDebug() << "-----------------------------P-5------------------------------------";
}

bool loginDialog::isDecrypted()
{
    return this->decrypted;
}

std::string loginDialog::getPassword()
{
    return this->password;
}
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    byte ivec[16];
    byte salt[32];

    CryptoPP::OS_GenerateRandomBlock(false, salt, sizeof(salt));
    CryptoPP::OS_GenerateRandomBlock(false, ivec, sizeof(ivec));

    std::string v;

    CryptoPP::HexEncoder hex(new CryptoPP::StringSink(v));
    hex.Put(salt, sizeof(salt));
    hex.MessageEnd();

    QMessageBox::about(this,tr("Test1"),tr(v.c_str()));
    QMessageBox::about(this,tr("Test1"),tr("XXX"));
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{   
    std::string password;
    if(getEnterPassword(password)==false)
    {
        QMessageBox::about(this,tr("Failed"),tr("Password does not match!"));
    }
    else
    {
        QMessageBox::about(this,tr("Failed"),tr("Password match!"));
    }
}

bool MainWindow::getEnterPassword(std::string &password)
{
loginDialog passwordWindow;
qDebug() << "-----------------------------P-8------------------------------------";
passwordWindow.setModal(true);
qDebug() << "-----------------------------P-9------------------------------------";
passwordWindow.exec();
qDebug() << "-----------------------------P-10------------------------------------";

qDebug() << "-----------------------------P-1------------------------------------";
loginDialog passwordWindowRe;
qDebug() << "-----------------------------P-11------------------------------------";
passwordWindowRe.setModal(true);
qDebug() << "-----------------------------P-12------------------------------------";
passwordWindowRe.exec();
qDebug() << "-----------------------------P-13------------------------------------";

//qDebug() << passwordWindow.getPassword().c_str();
//qDebug() << passwordWindowRe.getPassword().c_str();

qDebug() << "-----------------------------P-14------------------------------------";
if(passwordWindow.getPassword() == passwordWindowRe.getPassword())
{
    qDebug() << "-----------------------------P-15------------------------------------";
    password = passwordWindow.getPassword();
    qDebug() << "-----------------------------P-16------------------------------------";
    return true;
    qDebug() << "-----------------------------P-17------------------------------------";
}
else
{
   qDebug() << "-----------------------------P-18------------------------------------";
   return false;
}
}
```

And the most important:
**testAndroid4.pro**

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2015-12-02T17:56:00
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = testAndroid4
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp \
    logindialog.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
    logindialog.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui \
    logindialog.ui

CONFIG += mobility
MOBILITY = 


INCLUDEPATH += C:\Temp\openssl\OpenSSL-for-Android-Prebuilt\openssl-1.0.2\include\

LIBS += -LC:\Temp\openssl\OpenSSL-for-Android-Prebuilt\openssl-1.0.2\armeabi-v7a\lib -lssl
LIBS += -LC:\Temp\openssl\OpenSSL-for-Android-Prebuilt\openssl-1.0.2\armeabi-v7a\lib -lcrypto


ANDROID_EXTRA_LIBS += C:\Users\niki\Downloads\android-ndk-r10e\sources\cxx-stl\stlport\libs\armeabi-v7a\libstlport_shared.so
ANDROID_EXTRA_LIBS += C:\Temp\cryptopp\cryptopp-5.6.2-android-14\cryptopp-android-14\lib1\libcryptopp.so

INCLUDEPATH += C:\Temp\cryptopp\cryptopp-5.6.2-android-14\cryptopp-android-14\include\cryptopp\

LIBS += -LC:\Users\niki\Downloads\android-ndk-r10e\sources\cxx-stl\stlport\libs\armeabi-v7a -lstlport_shared
LIBS += -LC:\Temp\cryptopp\cryptopp-5.6.2-android-14\cryptopp-android-14\lib1 -lcryptopp



DISTFILES += \
    ../../../../Temp/cryptopp/cryptopp-5.6.2-android-14/cryptopp-android-14/lib1/libcryptopp.so
```

When I start the program and press pushButton2 it appears logindialog. When I enter something into it and press logindialog's button the program is dieing. If I comment in .pro file the cryptopp lines the program works properly. If I leave empty the lineEdit and push passwordButton of logindialog, it again ask me about password and I give blank, but again die - see the second log appears(notice the P1,P2,P3... in both logs). I took openssl from [this](https://github.com/emileb/OpenSSL-for-Android-Prebuilt) link and criptopp from [this](https://github.com/noloader/cryptopp-5.6.2-android-14). I think the problem is somewhere with cryptopp. How can I increase stack and heap size for qt android? I don't think this is the issue and have read something about "stack trace debuging" but don't know how to do it. Never mind, what could be the issue in this case?

After edition:

I have tested it on my android 4.1.2 device LG optimus L1 e410. No matter if I test it on AVD with android 23/14/18/16 -> it is failing. If cryptopp is commented all goes OK. log2 compile output is same as first one with difference in time only.

After edition 2:

Application log for cryptopp usage for pushButton:

```
I/Adreno200-EGL( 6066): Reconstruct Branch: NOTHING
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 6066): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
F/libc    ( 6066): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x54ff002e (code=1), thread 6156 (le.testAndroid4)
I/DEBUG   (  147): pid: 6066, tid: 6156, name: le.testAndroid4  >>> org.qtproject.example.testAndroid4 <<<
I/ActivityManager(  457): Process org.qtproject.example.testAndroid4 (pid 6066) has died.


"org.qtproject.example.testAndroid4" died.
```

See pushButton in mainwindow.cpp and commented thigs in mainwindow.h(they are not commented really).

Comment: That's alot of code.  Can you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Done. I have extract if from a lot of more code, but now I erased redundant parts.

Comment: Its not clear to me if this is an OpenSSL, Crypto++ or QT issue. The best I can tell, this is a QT problem because of the re-occurring *`java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: View_paddingEnd`* exception. You should probably reduce this further by removing the QT gear, and using a command line driver. You can use `adb` to push the reduced program to `/data/local/tmp`. Then see if it crashes.

Comment: Where is your code calling a `cryptopp` function, I can't see it.

Comment: I am using QT Creator for windows. What removing 'QT gears means'. I have tested it on real device via ADB and it crashed. It is not using cryptopp - that is the strange, even not including the headers, but it crashes when the lib is linked in .pro file, but I have used it in another project like including it and it crashes again. Openssl does not crash! I will edit to show you.

Comment: I have edit it see after edition 2.

Answer (score 2):

You are manually loading `libstlport_shared.so`, I suppose it's because it is needed by `libcryptopp.so`.

By default Qt, uses a STL library (`libgnustl_shared.so` in my case, you can check this in your android-build\libs\armeabi-v7a folder after compilation) upon compilation and deployment. If your crypto library uses a different one (apparently `libstlport_shared.so`), loading it manually from the .pro file as you did (`ANDROID_EXTRA_LIBS +=` , `LIB +=`) will make the `libcryptopp.so` loadable, but you'll most likely get a seg fault whenever you'll pass a STL object (`std::string` for instance) from your code to a crypto function.

Two environments (your code and crypto one) are not using the same STL implementation, so they cannot safely send any STL object to each other without a serious potential segmentation fault (as one will consider objects as created from its own implementation when it was actually created with the other one: objects will most likely have different attributes....it's like forcing a cast between two completely different types).

You can verify this like that:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    byte ivec[16];
    byte salt[32];

    qDebug() << "Calling OS_GenerateRandomBlock";
    CryptoPP::OS_GenerateRandomBlock(false, salt, sizeof(salt));
    qDebug() << "Calling OS_GenerateRandomBlock";
    CryptoPP::OS_GenerateRandomBlock(false, ivec, sizeof(ivec));

    std::string v;

    qDebug() << "Passing std::string to CryptoPP::StringSink";    
    CryptoPP::StringSink* sink = new CryptoPP::StringSink(v);

    qDebug() << "Creating HexEncoder";    
    CryptoPP::HexEncoder hex( sink );

    hex.Put(salt, sizeof(salt));
    hex.MessageEnd();

    QMessageBox::about(this,tr("Test1"),tr(v.c_str()));
    QMessageBox::about(this,tr("Test1"),tr("XXX"));
}
```

Please confirm, but I'm pretty sure you'll see "Passing std::string to CryptoPP::StringSink" but not "Creating HexEncoder".

You should recompile `libcryptopp.so` to have it use the same STL implmentation as your main program (and cross your finger that the lib will work with that STL implementation).

Comment: Everything you saied looks logical. Yes there is file `libgnustl_shared.so` in android-build\libs\armeabi-v7a folder. I've tried `CryptoPP::StringSink* sink = new CryptoPP::StringSink(v);` and log is `E/ActivityManager(  457):     1.7% 16029/le.testAndroid4: 0% user + 1.7% kernel
F/libc    (16029): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x54ff002e (code=1), thread 16081 (le.testAndroid4)
I/DEBUG   (  147): pid: 16029, tid: 16081, name: le.testAndroid4  >>> org.qtproject.example.testAndroid4 <<<

"org.qtproject.example.testAndroid4" died.`. I'm upvoting your answer for now and will compile to check it.

Comment: I had a similar problem in the past and could not make my third party library compile with a different STL implementation. Hopefully you'll manage to do this here.

Comment: *"If your crypto library uses a different one..."* - yes, the Crypto++ library use `libstlport_shared.so` by default; see [setenv-android.sh](http://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/setenv-android.sh). The user can change it simply by `setenv-android.sh gnu`. STLport was selected by default because of GNU's toxic licensing terms; see [Two Qt issues with Crypto++ on Android](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/cryptopp-users/-d8op4wOJK4/zQfMzO6IEQAJ) on the Crypto++ mailing list.

Comment: @jww: Thanks for the clarification on that.